# Error: Cannot assign value "$event" to template variable "address". Template variables are read-only

Tags: angular, angular-forms

i'm new to angular ,so i'm using template driven  forms and i want to bind data using the response from API ,

my ts code

```js
getAdress(f: FormGroup) {
  this.checkOut.getAdress(f.controls.email.value).subscribe((response: any) => {
    this.address = response.Address[0].address
    this.City = response.Address[0].city
    this.postalAddress = response.Address[0].postalAddress

    console.log(response)
  })
}
```

my html code

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-title">SHIPPING ADDRESS</div>
  <hr />
  <div class="card-body">
    <form #f="ngForm">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="firstName" class="form-label ms-3">First Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              id="firstName"
              name="firstName"
              #firstName="ngModel"
              [(ngModel)]="NAME"
              aria-describedby="emailHelp"
              required
              minlength="5"
            />
            <span
              class="input-dirty"
              *ngIf="!firstName?.valid && (firstName?.dirty || firstName?.touched)"
            >
              First Name required</span
            >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="lastName" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              name="lastName"
              id="lastName"
              #lastName="ngModel"
              ngModel
              required
              minlength="5"
            />
            <span
              class="input-dirty"
              *ngIf="!lastName?.valid && (lastName?.dirty || lastName?.touched)"
              >Last Name required</span
            >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="address" class="form-label">Address</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          name="address"
          id="address"
          #address="ngModel"
          required
          minlength="20"
          [(ngModel)]="address"
        />
        <span class="input-dirty" *ngIf="!address?.valid && (address?.dirty || address?.touched)">
          Enter valid Address</span
        >
        <input type="text" class="form-control mt-1" name="address" id="address" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="state" class="form-label">country</label>
            <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
              <option selected>Select Country</option>
              <option value="1">India</option>
              <option value="2">USA</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="zipcode" class="form-label">ZIP/Postal Code</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              name="zipcode"
              id="zipcode"
              #zipcode="ngModel"
              [(ngModel)]="postalAddress"
              required
              minlength="5"
              (change)="ngOnChanges(f)"
            />
            <!-- <div class="text-danger"
    *ngIf="registerForm.controls.zipcode.touched">
    Email is required</div> -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="city" class="form-label">City</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              name="city"
              id="city"
              [(ngModel)]="City"
              #city="ngModel"
              required
              minlength="4"
            />
            <span class="input-dirty" *ngIf="!city?.valid && (city?.dirty || city?.touched)">
              Enter valid City</span
            >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="state" class="form-label">state/province</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            name="state"
            id="state"
            ngModel
            #state="ngModel"
            required
            minlength="4"
          />
          <span class="input-dirty" *ngIf="!state?.valid && (state?.dirty || state?.touched)">
            Enter valid state</span
          >
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Error log

- Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
  Error: Cannot assign value "$event" to template variable "address". Template variables are read-only.
  at _AstToIrVisitor.visitPropertyWrite (/home/inficloud/gorilla_wireless_UI/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:9048:31)
  at PropertyWrite.visit (/home/inficloud/gorilla_wireless_UI/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:7666:28)
  at convertActionBinding (/home/inficloud/gorilla_wireless_UI/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:8615:49)
  at prepareEventListenerParameters (/home/inficloud/gorilla_wireless_UI/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:21240:27)
  at Object.params (/home/inficloud/gorilla_wireless_UI/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:22417:24)
  at /home/inficloud/gorilla_wireless_UI/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:22155:94
  at Array.map ()
  at /home/inficloud/gorilla_wireless_UI/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:22155:60
  at /home/inficloud/gorilla_wireless_UI/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:21406:87
  at Array.map ()
  at TemplateDefinitionBuilder.buildTemplateFunction (/home/inficloud/gorilla_wireless_UI/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:21406:60)
  at Object.compileComponentFromMetadata (/home/inficloud/gorilla_wireless_UI/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23179:58)
  at ComponentDecoratorHandler.compileFull (/home/inficloud/gorilla_wireless_UI/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/annotations/src/component.js:807:34)
  at _loop_2 (/home/inficloud/gorilla_wireless_UI/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/transform/src/compilation.js:731:39)
  at TraitCompiler.compile (/home/inficloud/gorilla_wireless_UI/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/transform/src/compilation.js:762:21)
  at IvyCompilationVisitor.visitClassDeclaration (/home/inficloud/gorilla_wireless_UI/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/transform/src/transform.js:56:43)

Comment: Why are you doing `#address="ngModel"`, since `[(ndModel)="address"` binding is already there?

Comment: The error is exactly what it says, you can't assign a value to a template variable (#address) which you are attempting to do (#address="...").

What are you actually trying to do there?

Comment: i'm getting this response from back end and i want to bind this data to input


{
  "Address": [
    {
    
      "addressType": "Home",
      "doorNumber": "",
      "address": "kamp",
      "postalAddress": "256",
      "country": "Uganda",
      "city": "Kampala",
      "state": null,
      "landmark": null,
      "isDeleted": null
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Check this part :

> TemplateRef name(address) and ngModel value (address) **must be different.**
> Meaning the `id` should be different to the `ngModel`

Try this

```js
#selectedAddress="ngModel"
minlength="20"
[(ngModel)]="address"
```

Comment: can you post one solution having ngModel and templateRef value same ?? 

My solution is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: Cannot assign value "$event" to template variable "digit1". Template variables are read-only.
```

I got this error when using the same name on ngModel='digit1' and @ViewChild('digit1').

```
 <ion-input #digitinput1 type="number" [(ngModel)]="digit1" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ion-input>
```

You must use diffrent names.